# Umbraco: How to check if a member is allowed to access a page programmatically

Tags: permissions, umbraco, member, umbraco8

I'm setting up a Umbraco 8 site for creating a prototype.
As I'm playing around with the default code of the Starter Kit, I wanted to change the behaviour of the top navigation.
Currently you can only hide pages for all visitors, but I want to only hide pages based on the members (group) permissions.

I see, that you can check, if a member is in a role with Role.IsUserInRole, but I cannot see a way to get the allowed roles for a page.

Do I need to get the roles and loop through them?
If yes, how do I get them?
If no, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working this way:

```
IContent content = base.Services.ContentService.GetById(item.Id);
PublicAccessEntry entry = base.Services.PublicAccessService.GetEntryForContent(content);
if (entry != null)
{
    foreach (var r in entry.Rules)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(r.RuleValue))
        {
            <a class="nav-link @(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model) ? "nav-link--active" : null)" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
        }
    }
}
else
{
    <a class="nav-link @(item.IsAncestorOrSelf(Model) ? "nav-link--active" : null)" href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
}
```

Maybe this needs some more work, as I guess the performance is not that good.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know there is a built-in dependency between Roles and Pages so you get roles for a page but consider setting certain roles that you need i.e **Pro**, **Free**, **Monthly Membership**...

For each role you may show / hide specific content, and to get all roles in your database use [GetAllRoles](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/MemberService/#getallroles) method.

Then loop through the roles and check if the logged in user is a member or not to give him right access.

---

After your second comment I went through an Umbraco V8 demo in which I applied the following which I suggest for you:

1. Create groups A & B
2. Create members A & B
3. Create Login and Logout form
4. Create 3 templates Master, Login & Page
5. Create 3 document types Master, Login & Page
6. Create one parent Content i.e Home
7. Create three childs Contents i.e Login, A & B
8. Show navigation menu item A for members of group A
9. Show navigation menu item B for members of group B
10. Deny access to page A for unregistered members
11. Deny access to page B for unregistered members

**Preview:**

[image: Umbraco membership]

**Code used in point 8 & 9:**

```
@{ 
    var isMemberofB = false;
    var isMemberofA = false;
}
```

---

```
 @{
            var myUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
            if (myUser != null)
            {
                <p class="ui red sub header">
                    <i class="user icon"></i>
                    you're logged in as @myUser.UserName
                    @{
                        isMemberofB = System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(myUser.UserName, "B");
                        if (isMemberofB)
                        {
                        <p class="ui green sub header">
                            <i class="user icon"></i>
                            you're a member of role B
                        </p>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isMemberofA = System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(myUser.UserName, "A");
                        if (isMemberofA)
                        {
                            <p class="ui green sub header">
                                <i class="user icon"></i>
                                you're a member of role A
                            </p>
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    @*This example shows how to use lazy loaded images, a sticky menu, and a simple text container*@
                    </p>
                }
        }
```

---

```
          <a href="#" class="ui right floated dropdown item">
            Dropdown <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                     <div class="menu">
                         @if (isMemberofA)
                         {
                             <div class="item">Link To Page A</div>
                         }
                         @if (isMemberofB)
                         {
                             <div class="item">Link To Page B</div>
                         }
                         <div class="divider"></div>
                         <div class="header">Header Item</div>
                         <div class="item">
                             <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                             Sub Menu
                             <div class="menu">
                                 <div class="item">Link Item</div>
                                 <div class="item">Link Item</div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="item">Link Item</div>
                     </div>
          </a>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly. As I understand you, you suggest to check, if a member has any roles instead of checking for a specific role. Am I right? If yes, then this is not suitable for me.

Comment: I don't see a difference when you said As I understand you, you suggest to check, if a member has any roles instead of checking for a specific role. 

If you know the role name then check for it only.

Quote: You mentioned "I want to only hide pages based on the members (group) permissions", in case there is other way than what I answered I want to know about it.

Comment: Let me give you an example: Member A has role A. Page B is only accessible for members in role B. I want to hide Page B in the navigation for members that are not part of role B. How can I know in the navigation control, that Page B is only permitted for role B?

Comment: How do you do steps 8 and 9 because this is actually what I'm looking for, only that I wrote about blacklisting and you are writing about whitelisting. As you might see from my own answer, I solved the problem programmatically, but if there is an out of the box solution, that would be a better way.

Comment: Oh ok, you do it hard-coded. So if you add another role, you have to update this. I think my solution is more suitable, as it is dynamic. But thanks for your efforts :)